# Why are almost all "turntable stands" and "Vinyl record storage units" made of wood? Does this have something to do with the sound quality?

Tags: sound-quality, turntable

Why are almost all "turntable stands" and "Vinyl record storage units" made of wood? Does this have something to do with the sound quality?

I prefer modern metal furniture and couldn't find a suitable turntable stand and vinyl record storage in online shops. Almost all offers are made of wood. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Define suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the modern world, vinyl records (like analog watches, radios, newspapers, steam trains, and paper journals) are a niche nostalgia product. Wood is the popular accompaniment for this, largely for aesthetic and thematic reasons. As an organic material, wood feels more "analog." It's quite common to see vinyl themed products that have an exaggerated "old timey" feel, to appeal to people who like records specifically because of their anachronistic associations.

When vinyl was more mainstream, it wasn't unusual to see stands and storage units made of metal. You might have better luck finding them secondhand.

You also don't necessarily need something specified for this, as long as the dimensions are a match. When I was growing up, my parents kept their vinyl in plastic milk crates (now there's some vintage nostalgia for you!). https://www.funkymooserecords.ca/blogs/stories/the-fundamental-guide-to-vinyl-record-storage